# Cannot install dependencies for C# extension, code-oss

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Cannot install C# package for vscode

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: linux, x86_64, name=manjaro, version=unknown

Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (linux / x64)' Failed to download from https://github.com/Samsung/netcoredbg/releases/download/1.2.0-825/netcoredbg-linux-amd64.tar.gz. Error code '404')
    Retrying from 'https://web.archive.org/web/20210704184708/https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/113926796/fc5bfc00-dc3b-11eb-8d47-f99c4dc1c4c6?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210704%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210704T184708Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=521e3d193946f1cd4598e55056b7597497e294322daa6827f3bf84d1be4e1d89&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=113926796&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dnetcoredbg-linux-amd64.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream' (NaN KB) Done!
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (linux / x64)'

Failed at stage: installPackage
C# Extension was unable to install its dependencies. Please check your internet connection. If you use a proxy server, please visit https://aka.ms/VsCodeCsharpNetworking
```

Comment: Having the same problem on arch linux in oss code

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, its because OSS doesn't have the full marketplace due to it only allowing fully open source extensions, etc...
so you have to do the change on the json

Any way since you're using manajaro theres a aur that injects the small piece of code [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/code-marketplace/)